# JSON data output from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have connected to a mysql database and I am trying to use jquery to populate a drop down menu using data from the database and JSON.

I do not have much experience with JSON, but I have read many articles and searched the web for tutorials.

In my PHP to connect to the database, the last lines format and output the JSON correctly:
`$response = $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "(" . json_encode($colors) . ")";`
`echo $response;`

In the javascript, I use:
`$.getJSON("db.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data){ //loop that populates the drop down  });`

I have jquery set up to grab the JSON and populate the drop down, which is also working correctly. However, the JSON data that is created in the PHP is outputted at the top of my generated page.

i.e.,
`([{"color":"Purple"},{"color":"Red"},{"color":"Blue"},{"color":"Pink"},{"color":"Yello"}])`

How do I still access the `jsoncallback` without outputting the JSON on my page?

Comment: Is it PHP or JavaScript that adds the JSON to your page? We need more details to help you with this one since nothing is wrong with the code above. Is db.php the same file as the main file?

Comment: you can return a drop down list from PHP, do you have to create a drop down list with javascript?

Comment: Hm could you show the code that populates the dropdown? Or do you have an online place we could see this in action?

Comment: @dany Doing it by JSON is an elegant way. I'm sure there is an easy solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same file to generate the JSON output aswell and generate your normal pages, which is why the JSON will output at the top of the page.

Try wrapping the JSON output in an if statement that prevents output unless you reqire it, ie when you make an AJAX request, or move the JSON output to another file such as ajax.php that is specifically for handling AJAX requests. Simple example below.

Updates JS, passing over a new actions param.

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php?jsoncallback=?", { action: 'get_colors' },  function(data){ //loop that populates the drop down })
```

New PHP file ajax.php

```
// Include required other php files, etc
switch ($_GET['action']) {

    case 'get_colors':
        $response = $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "(" . json_encode($colors) . ")";
        echo $response;
    break;

 }
```

Comment: Great answer. I moved the request to another file. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score -2):

Is the following inside a script block? If not, it needs to be.

```
echo $response;
```

Like so:

```
echo "<script>{$response}</script>";
```

Comment: Why would you need to put the response between script tags?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. WHY does it NEED to be inside a script block?

Comment: I shouldn't be posting answers after midnight.